# Error En Microsoft Visual Studio, No se puede agregar una referencia a "proyecto"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp

estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en asp.net y MySQL, el caso es que estoy probando un método de encriptación y desencriptación para algunos datos que son delicados, el método que estoy utilizando es el 3DES, tengo un problema al momento de poner de referencia mi librería de clase, que la librería de clase se llama Web.Logica y ahí tengo el método de encriptación y desencriptación, tengo un proyecto que se llama, Encriptacion.aspx donde llamare a mi biblioteca de clases, pero para eso ocupo referenciar la biblioteca en mi proyecto, pero me sale un error al momento de querer poner la referencia, el cual es el siguiente:

> "No se puede agregar una referencia a "Web.Logica". si se agrega este
> proyecto como referencia, se producirá una dependencia circular."
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias:).

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Tu pregunta necesita mucho más detalles que una simple captura de pantalla del error. Te sugiero que indiques con mayor claridad lo que estás haciendo, puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución, lo que pasa es que a mi biblioteca de clases le agregue una referencia de mi proyecto de prueba_encriptacion y al momento de querer poner la referencia a mi proyecto de prueba_encriptacion me lanzaba ese error porque lo había referenciado en mi biblioteca de clases, ya solo quite la referencia eh intente de nuevo y funciono:D